# @GeneratedValue when create a new instance

Tags: java, jpa

I have an entity with a @GeneratedValue(). I know there are different generation types. My question is: Is there a generation typ which generate the ID when i create a new instance of the entity? I need the id of my object to create another object which have the id as FK, but i dont want to persist the objekt before creating the other object. Thanks for help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<strike>You can call the `store()` method. Store method doesn't persist the object in the DB as yet. It creates a proxy object in the hibernate cache layer and returns that proxy object, with the primary key populated (yes, the auto generated value is available). You can use this value for your other object as you wanted. Once done, when you flush the session, all the objects, are persisted in the DB.</strike>

This answer is now outdated/obsolete since the "store" function does not exist anymore. It needs to be deleted, but I'm unable to do so, because this is the accepted answer.

Comment: This is `Hibernate` specific and wouldn't let you port you application across different ORMs which is why `JPA` is usually used in the first place.

Comment: Hello! I am trying to use this method on my entity (EX: myEntity.store(), or myRepostitory.store(myEntity)), both of which don't exist. Where did you find the .store() method and how do we properly call it?

Answer (score 0):

You do not have to worry about getting the generated ID at all. Just set up the object relationship on Java side (using the setter methods) and on `persist()` JPA would make sure that the PK generated is set as an FK on the dependent object.

To give you an example, if you had the following entity classes

```
@Entity
public class PKClass {

    @Id @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "PK_ID")
    private Long id;

    // getters/setters
}

@Entity
public class FKClass {

    @Id @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "FK_ID")
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "PK_ID")
    private PKClass pk;

    // getters/setters
}
```

You would persist them (without worrying about the primary key) as

```
// create a new transaction
EntityTransaction tx = em.getTransaction();
tx.begin();

// setup Java relationships
PKClass pk = new PKClass();
FKClass fk = new FKClass();
fk.setPK(pk);

// persist
em.persist(fk);

// close transaction
tx.commit();
```